# How do I use VirtualBox to run XP off of a dual-boot drive in Ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: windows-xp, virtualbox, ubuntu-10.04, virtualization

I recently upgraded to 10.04 and am pretty pleased. I have XP on the same drive, different partition. I would like to use VirtualBox to run XP while I am running Ubuntu. I've seen some directions for using VMWare but I don't want to install another piece of software. Here are some questions:

1. What version of Virtualbox works with 10.04?
2. What are the steps to create a setup that runs off a pre-existing XP installation?
3. Are there easier ways of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to answer your questions:

1. You can install the last version from official site, or you can install the last version of OSE (Open Source edition) from your repo: `sudo apt-get install virtualbox-ose`
2. There is no way in VirtualBox to run OS directly from physical partition, but there is the way to convert physical partition to virtual drive. Check this [article](http://blarts.wordpress.com/2007/12/06/how-to-run-virtualbox-using-a-physical-partition-using-ubuntu-feisty-fawn/)
3. The easier way is the new Windows XP installation in the VirtualBox, but if you need to use your existing installation - use VMWare.